# Plot a vertical line, in a time series, using pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

**my main question is how do i plot a vertical line when my x axis represents a datetime series? e.g. 1st Jan to 12th Jan, 2106**

Some things I tried were:

I already have a graph, made from a Dataframe with dates. I need to plot a vertical line at x=somedate.

```
days = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2016-01-07', end='2016-01-031', freq='D')
example=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(7,32),index=days)
gp=example.plot()
```

I tried using

```
gp.axvline(x=days[0].date())
```

However, it shows an error that ordinal line >=1.
How can i plot?

Comment: what exactly is ``day``? I can only see ``days``. Also please provide the full traceback of the error.

Comment: that was a typo. It is 'days'. I will provide the traceback in a moment too. However, my main question is how do i plot a vertical line when my x axis represents a datetime series? e.g. 1st Jan to 12th Jan, 2106

Comment: @CoderBC - Provide a *minimal* working example and it will be a lot easier to help you. Just 1-2 datapoints and how you would go about plotting them.

Comment: I've treid to make ammends

Comment: Still missing the whole traceback. But nevertheless ``gp.axvline(days[5].date())`` works on my computer. Could you also add ``pandas`` tag and edit into your question which python/mpl/pandas version you are using?

Comment: Your code works for me. The `.date()` call is unnecessary but it does not hurt.

Comment: The problem is that the vertical line is draw in the left border of the xaxis so you are not seeing the result. I create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my comment above with some extra code. Following your code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

days = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2016-01-07', end='2016-01-031', freq='D')
example=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(7,32),index=days)
gp=example.plot()

gp.axvline(x=days[0].date())

# And now the interesting part
# I add one day to the previous left xlim
gp.set_xlim(left = days[0].date() - dt.timedelta(days = 1))
gp.figure.canvas.draw()
gp.figure.show()
```